# Slow query performance in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization, groupwise-maximum

I would like to find out what causes the slow execution of my MySQL query here. It's 1 row fetched in 0.0017s (3.6215s) How can i optimize this?

```
SELECT  hadmlog.hpercode as 'HOSPITAL NUMBER', FLOOR (hadmlog.patage) as 'AGE', CONCAT (hperson.patlast, ',  ', hperson.patfirst, '  ',hperson.patmiddle) as 'PROFILE', hcity.ctyname as 'DISTRICT', hadmlog.disdate as 'DISCHARGED DATE' 
FROM hadmlog 
INNER JOIN hperson ON hadmlog.hpercode=hperson.hpercode 
INNER JOIN haddr ON hadmlog.hpercode=haddr.hpercode 
INNER JOIN hcity ON haddr.ctycode=hcity.ctycode 
WHERE hadmlog.patage BETWEEN '1' AND  '4' 
  AND  hperson.patsex = 'M' 
  AND DATE(hadmlog.disdate) = DATE(curdate()) 
  AND  haddr.haddrdte = ( select max(haddrdte) 
                          from haddr 
                          where haddr.hpercode = hperson.hpercode ) 
ORDER BY Profile;
```

Comment: Please provide the explain plan....

Comment: ... and provide complete CREATE TABLE, including indices, for all tables used also.

Comment: ... and tell us how many records do you have per each table

Comment: What do you mean by "It's 1 row fetched in 0.0017s (3.6215s)"?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix the query:

```
SELECT al.hpercode as HOSPITAL_NUMBER, FLOOR(al.patage) as AGE, 
       CONCAT_WS(' ', p.patlast, p.patfirst, p.patmiddle) as PROFILE,
        c.ctyname as DISTRICT, al.disdate as DISCHARGED_DATE 
FROM hadmlog al JOIN
     hperson p
     ON al.hpercode = p.hpercode JOIN
     haddr a
     ON al.hpercode = a.hpercode JOIN
     hcity c
     ON a.ctycode = c.ctycode 
WHERE al.patage BETWEEN 1 AND 4 AND
      p.patsex = 'M' AND
      al.disdate >= curdate() AND
      al.disdate < curdate() + INTERVAL 1 day AND
      a.haddrdte = (select max(h2.haddrdte) 
                    from haddr h2
                    where h2.hpercode = p.hpercode
                   ) 
ORDER BY Profile;
```

Some of the changes are cosmetic (such as the table aliases and `CONCAT_WS()`).  The more relevant changes are:

- `patage` appears to be a number, so make the comparisons numbers.  Strings can impede the optimizer.
- `date(disdate)` can also impede the optimizer.

Then, for this query, I am guessing that you want an indexes:

- `hadmlog(disdate, patage)`

And then you want indexes on the `JOIN` keys used for the other tables.